# Dynamically adding AnchorPane defined in FXML to Tabs and getting later access to this Pane content

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I would like to add `TableView` dynamically to tabs. Now I would like to have access to controllers. I don't know how to do this. Here is code:

sample.fxml code:

```
<GridPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10">
    <TabPane fx:id="tabPane">
    </TabPane>
</GridPane>
```

Controller:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TabPane tabPane;

    public TabPane getTabPane() {
        return tabPane;
    }

    public void setTabPane(TabPane tabPane) {
        this.tabPane = tabPane;
    }
}
```

FXMLTableView.fxml code:

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx"
        xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
        fx:controller="sample.ControllerFXMLTableView"
        prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">

    <TableView>
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="columnName" text="name"/>
            <TableColumn text="surname"/>
        </columns>
    </TableView>
</AnchorPane>
```

and controller:

```
public class ControllerFXMLTableView {

    @FXML
    private TableColumn columnName;

    public ControllerFXMLTableView() {}

    public TableColumn getColumnName() {
        return columnName;
    }

    public void setColumnName(TableColumn columnName) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }
}
```

And in Main.java I have this code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loaderSample = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        Parent root = loaderSample.load();

        Controller controller = loaderSample.getController();

        TabPane tabPane = controller.getTabPane();

        List<String> listMonths = List.of("January", "February", "March", "April");

        listMonths.forEach(itemList -> {
            try {
                Tab tabTemp = new Tab(itemList.toString());
                AnchorPane anchorPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLTableView.fxml"));
                tabTemp.setContent(anchorPane);
                tabPane.getTabs().add(tabTemp);
            } catch(Exception ex){}
        });


        stage.setTitle("Hello World");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Not sure this is the proper way I should do it. Would like to know the acceptable splution.  Now I would like to have access to column marked with `fx:id="columnName"`. How to get access to `ControllerFXMLTableView` for each tab?

12 months is not too many to just code it in fxml (and have no problem with dynamic code), but this just asks for a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to get access to ControllerFXMLTableView for each tab ?

Simply do it within the `forEach` loop:

```
 FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLTableView.fxml"));
 AnchorPane anchorPane = loader.load();
 ControllerFXMLTableView tabController = loader.getController();
 TableColumn column = tabController.getColumnName();
```

Edit: to sore refences for later use you can define an appropriate container, a `Map<String,TableColumn> columns = new HashMap<>();` for example, and use it: 
`columns.put(itemList, tabController.getColumnName());`

Comment: I have this `AnchorPane` on every tab, should I keep list of those controllers or something? My intentions is that I just added those `AnchorPane`'s on tabs. And NOW the only thing I have is `TabPane`, from this pane I get tabs and then I change (for example) names of columns.

Comment: I want get access to controller after leaving loop.

Comment: You can store the references in a `List<TableColumn>` or `Map<String,TableColumn>`

Comment: I thought there is a better solution than storing references.